# Can't use multiple classes in Protractor

Tags: javascript, angular, testing, protractor, end-to-end

i have a problem. I try to add Group name in protractor but my tests are fail. Here is my code:

```
<div _ngcontent-7cfe-55="" class="form-group col-md-12">
  <label _ngcontent-7cfe-55="">Group name</label>
  <input _ngcontent-7cfe-55="" class="form-control ng-pristine ng-valid ng-touched" type="text">
</div>
```

and here is my test for this element:

```
element(by.css('.form-control.ng-pristine.ng-valid.ng-touched')).sendKeys();
```

can someone know what's wrong in this code?

Comment: First of all class names like `ng-pristine ng-valid ng-touched` are dynamically added by angular js based on the element state and validation conditions. So it's always a bad practice to use these type of class names as element locators. And also can you kindly post the error that your getting because without logs it would be difficult to debug the issue. Thanks.

Comment: I agree with @SudharsanSelvaraj.  Also I don't think your input has `ng-touched` when it first loads.  It is probably `ng-untouched` until you give it focus, so your locator is probably not correct